# Fixed-length dump in itsdangerous

Tags: python, cryptography, digital-signature

How does one go about generating a fixed length signed string using [itsdangerous](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/)? Obviously, I need to be able to unsign it.

```
>>> s.dumps('a')
'ImEi.Th5lgzQ2gyF7GqIcSBaYln70Q4Q'
>>> s.dumps('aaa')
'ImFhYSI.RoXzD0sEJQhrHhpp-GEZN7q3Rfo'
>>> s.dumps('aaaa')
'ImFhYWEi.hK4xGo5NA9OANCNV21yXEx41ntA'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you sign something you're hashing it, but you also need the original to later verify the signature. If the data that you want to sign is of variable length then the itsdangerous "signature" will be of variable length, because it contains the data.

Having said that, you may note that itsdangerous adds a separator `.`. The part after the separator is the fixed length signature, but you will have to retain the data somehow to actually verify the signature.

Comment: I noticed the first part (before the separator) is always the same regardless of the secret key and the salt. If I can retain this value, would it be secure to send the client only the second part of the signed string (after the separator)? Do you see any problems with this?

Comment: Yes. The first part is simply a base64 encoding of the data surrounded by `"` which is the default JSON encoding of the passed object.

Comment: Woah, I just noticed that. I had no idea the client could just decode the first part without any secret keys.

Comment: A digital signature doesn't provide confidentiality of the data. I guess you have to understand the difference between encryption and signature.

Comment: @webo Did my answer help? Do you have any problems with it?